# Summing multiple row values of various columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I need to add row value of various columns and store it in same(or new) dataframe.
eg:
The dataframe looks something like this:

```
id  col1  col2  col3  col4 ...  col50
 1    1     12    3     44         0
 1    7      0    7      2         10
 1    2      3    0      4         9
 3    9      0    1      0         0
 3    1      1   11      1         0
```

And the expected values should be:

```
id  col1  col2  col3  col4...  col50
 1    10   15    10    46        19
 3    10    1    12     1         0
```

If I use `tmp2 = tmp2.iloc[:,1:50].sum()`, it changes the dimension of the dataframe.

Comment: Do you want to sum the values of `rows` for each columns or you want sum the values of each  column individually ? if  you are looking aggregate these over the rows then `df.agg(['sum'])` .

Comment: you should accept the answer which works for you  or atleast upvote, already have nice answer supplied by fellow colleagues ..

Comment: @pygo that is exactly what I was thinking! All the answers are working (3 of them suggest the same thing), accepting anyone is doing injustice to others. Let me just upvote them without accepting any.

Answer (score 5):

This is a **grouping aggregation** by `id`. Therefore, use a `GroupBy` object:

```
res = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).sum()

print(res)

   id  col1  col2  col3  col4  col50
0   1    10    15    10    50     19
1   3    10     1    12     1      0
```

Answer (score 4):

Using pandas [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function in combination with `sum()` does the trick

```
df.groupby(['id']).sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a pivot table and setting the id as an index:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(5, 4)), columns=["ID","A","B","C"])
print(df)
```

Raw df:

```
   ID  A  B  C
0   1  0  0  1
1   1  0  0  1
2   0  1  0  2
3   1  2  0  2
4   1  2  0  0

pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index="ID",values=["A","B","C"], aggfunc=np.sum)
print(pivoted_df)
```

This returns:

```
    A  B  C
ID         
0   1  0  2
1   4  0  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another approach with `groupby` using Single Grouping Column, Single Aggregation Function.

```
>>> df.groupby('id').agg('sum')
    col1  col2  col3  col4  col50
id
1     10    15    10    50     19
3     10     1    12     1      0
```

However, with `agg` you can use `sum()`, `mean()`, and `max()` etc, However, it will also facilitates Multiple Aggregation Functions like `agg(['sum', 'mean'])` or  `agg(['min', 'max'])`